# Error al guardar en una variable una promesa JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Como puedo guardar un valor de una promesa en javascript ya e probado con esto

```
function loadImage(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}
var image = loadImage(image);
image.then(result => {
            return result;
        });
```

Y no funciona me sale algo así cuando imprimo la variable en la consola.

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__
:
Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]
:
"resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]
:
img
```

Pero si imprimo la variable de image desde la función de loadImage dentro de la promesa me sale la configuracion de la imagen normal.

Comment: Te va a aparecer si quieres tener el resultado debes hacer un async await

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asi como te dice el comentario puedes ocupar async/await que estaria esperando a que se carge tu imagen y despues podria ejecutar el .then()

```
function loadImage(url){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const image = new Image();
        image.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(image);
        });
        image.src = url;
    });
}
async function callLoadImage(){
    var image = loadImage(image);
    await image.then(result => {
        return result;
    });
}
```